# Scrolling Image

Tags: css

Basically I am trying to to make a forum made using MyBB look more personalized from the current theme. Currently the theme I have is using a 1 pixel wide 100 pixels and is using the following code to repeat that accross the background off the header to give it a gradient look:

```
background: #202020 url(images/1/header.png) top left repeat-x;
```

What I'm looking to do is have a scrolling images there. To make sure it's 100% clear check out this link and look at the header.
[Click to be Taken to Example](http://thebattlecraft.net)

So basically how do I do pretty much exactly what they have done on that page with a scrolling images?

Edit: If it helps at all here is the link to the site. I'm making it for a friend:
[Click](http://gatecrafters.comlu.com/forum/index.php)

Edit2: Logo's full css looks like this:

```
#logo {
background: #202020 url(images/1/pan.jpg) top left repeat-x;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this: (see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/Sr8pd/))

The HTML:

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 321px;
    background: url(http://www.vector-finder.com/site-images/too_big/fantasy_banner_vector.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

The JS:

```
var banner_width = 512;
var banner_x = 0;
function moveBanner() {
    banner_x = (banner_x - 1) % banner_width;
    $('#header').css('background-position', banner_x + 'px 0');
}
setInterval(moveBanner, 50);
```

Comment: This may sound like a pretty basic question but where does the js  and the HTML go? I'm only sure how to implement the CSS the other parts I'm not so sure.

Comment: it could go in many places, I recommend putting it at the end of the page, just before the `</body>` tag, like this: `<script language="javascript"> var banner_width = ...etc etc </script></body>`

Comment: In case it helps I added the link to the site I'm making in the original post. This is a forum made with MyBB which means I did not code the stuff there. The header yes does have that already by looking at it with google chrome inspect. I also added in the full logo code as off now. The logo code comes from a global.css file which contains all the css stuff. Are you saying put the JS in the CSS file or another one? (assuming another since you said body tag but will it still be global then?)

Comment: Ok so in your case you want to change the JS a bit, to say `$('#logo')` instead of `$('#header')` (because of how the html is built in that particular page). I'm not familiar with MyBB so I can't tell you how to add JS, you'll have to research that elsewhere :) but I can assure you, when you run that piece of code, it will work.

Comment: Oh, also, `banner_width` is `633` in your case (not `512`)

Comment: Okay I will go and ask on the MyBB support forums and see where I should go about implementing the Java script. I will get back to you another comment if I get a solution.